# How to display the updated state in the redux store

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am new to redux. I have a form which i need to print the data entered in the form. I am updating the redux state through the local state,but unable to display the state variables through mapStateToProps method.

Thanks in advance

//Form component in App.js File

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {action1} from './Actions/action1'
import './App.css';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import Display from './Components/Displaylist'

const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
   return{
   submitHandler:(details)=>dispatch(action1(details))
   }
}

class App extends Component {

  state={
    FirstName:'', 
    LastName:'', 
    Age: '' 
 }


nameHandler=(event)=>{

    this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value});
}

SubmitHandler=(event)=>{
   event.preventDefault()
   /*
   const firstname=this.state.details.FirstName
   const lastname=this.state.details.LastName
   const age=this.state.details.Age
   */
   this.props.submitHandler(this.state)
}

  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <form onSubmit={this.SubmitHandler}>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <input 
                     type="text"
                     placeholder="FirstName"
                     value={this.state.FirstName}
                     onChange={this.nameHandler}
                     className="form-control"
                     name="FirstName"
                     />
                     </div>

                     <div className="form-group">
                     <input
                       type="text"
                       placeholder="LastName"
                       value={this.state.LastName}
                       onChange={this.nameHandler}
                       className="form-control"
                       name="LastName"
                       />
                     </div>

                     <div className="form-group">
                       <input
                       type="text"
                       placeholder="Age"
                       value={this.state.Age}
                       onChange={this.nameHandler}
                       className="form-control"
                       name="Age"
                       />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                       <button type="submit" >Submit Form</button>
                       </div>
                </form>
              <Display/>
     </div>
  );
}
}




export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps) (App);
```

//action component

```
import {SUBMISSION} from '../Constants/actiontypes'
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4'

export const action1=(body)=>{
    console.log(body)
 return{
     type:SUBMISSION,
     payload:{
     id:uuidv4(),
     body
     }
 }

}
```

//reducer component -->I am using combined reducer even i have only one action

```
import {SUBMISSION} from '../Constants/actiontypes'

const reducer1=(state=[],action)=>{

     if(action.type===SUBMISSION){

     return  [...state, action.payload];

   } 


    return state

}

export default reducer1
```

//combine reducer file

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import Reducer1 from './reducer1'

const allreducers=combineReducers({details:Reducer1})
export default allreducers
```

//Display file template

```
const Display=({details:{firstname,lastname,age}})=>{

    return(
        <div >
            <h1>Firstname:{firstname}</h1>
            <h1>LastName:{lastname}</h1>
            <h1>Age:{age}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Display
```

//DisplayList file--> I have imported the Display.js (above) file in this.And passing values through this file. Finally i imported this in my App.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import Display from './Display'

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
   return{
       details:state.details
   }
}

const List=({details})=>{
    console.log(details)
    return(
       <div>

      {details.map(de=>{
          console.log(de)
         return (
             <Display details={de} key ={de.id}/>
         )

      })}
      </div>
    )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(List)
```

I am unable to display the value that i have entered .

I am getting FirstName :
             LastName:
             Age:

but not their corresponding values.

Comment: When using redux, do not use local state. In App.js, you are updating the redux state, but displaying the local state. Write a mapStateToProps in App.js and display the redux state.

Comment: Hi Dharmendra, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you almost got it! The issue is with what you are passing to the Display component and how you are destructuring the props. Make these changes and it should work.

1. In the DisplayList Component, change

```
<Display details={de} key={de.id}/>
```

to

```
<Display details={de.body} key={de.id} />
```

2. In the Display Component, change

```
const Display=({details:{firstname,lastname,age}})
```

to

```
const Display = ({ details: { FirstName: firstname, LastName: lastname, Age: age }})
```

Here is a codesandbox example for your referrence:

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-obsht

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: It working for me. can you please elborate it why i need to use body in the Display component and why i need to destructure the props as {details:{FirstName:firstname} why not {details:{firstname}}

Comment: In your action creator, when you pass the data inside the payload, you are not mentioning the variable name for your "body" data and because of that, it creates a "body" variable and stores the data inside it. If you want to assign a different variable name, update your payload data like so, payload: { id:uuidv4(), formData: body } and use details.formData. For your second question, you need to use alias destructuring because the variable names differ from the details object data. If you don't want that, just update variable names, ({details: {FirstName}}) and Firstname: {FirstName}

Comment: Thanks for the explanation . I am clear now .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your initial state in `reducer`,

```
const reducer1=(state=[],action)=>{  ...  }
```

In `React` we have state `object`, but you initialized an `array` like `state=[]`.

You need to create an initial state object separately like,

```
const initialState = {
    details : []    //name it as `details`, because you are getting `state.details` in `DisplayList` component
}
```

Now you can update and return your state as,

```
const reducer1=(state=initialState, action)=>{

   if(action.type===SUBMISSION){
       return  {...state, details: [...state.details, action.payload] };
   } 

   return state
}
```

Comment: In DisplayList i am using state.details because in CombineReducer file i initialised my reducer1 as details .

Comment: When you do `combineReducers({details:Reducer1})` and access state using `namespace` you can finally iterate array from your state using `details.details.map(...)`

Comment: I tried with details.details.map but it got an error.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Then try to use normal reducer instead of combineReducer.